# Capture OPC-UA data using Wireshark

Tags: server, client, wireshark, opc-ua

I have established a connection between OPC UA server and client.I have set the security policy to none mode.I am able to view the opc ua nodes/attributes value updating in the Unified Automation application.I could trace the opc ua communication in Wireshark too. However, when I click on the ReadRequest or ReadResponse messages and expand the frame,I don't see the node id or node values in wireshark.There is only timestamp value visible.Could anyone help me how can i see the requested node/attribute id and value in wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

What do you see if not this? Have you dug down into the ReadRequest structure?

[image]

Comment: Hi, yes now I see.But the problem is I see only a single node with id 2259 , namespace = 0.However I have added 4 other nodes which belong to namespace 3.I dont see the value of those nodes.What could be the problem?

Comment: Maybe you’re looking at the wrong ReadRequest then? You’ll have to upload the capture or a screenshot for more help.

Comment: Also - you said you “added” these Nodes - does that mean you added MonitoredItems for these Nodes to a Subscription? You won’t see ReadRequests for those.

Comment: In UA expert , I have set the monitoring mode to Sampling and set publishing mode to enable.Sampling interval is 1s. I cant attach screenshot due to administrative reasons

Comment: Well, like I said, you won't see ReadRequests or ReadResponses for MonitoredItem change notifications. They will be embedded in PublishResponses and only sent when the value actually changed. The only identifying information will be the handle assigned by the client when the item was created.

Comment: But in the code, I am changing the values constantly, and I am not seeing the values even in publish requests and response messages. What should be the values in the UA expert to see the values in wireshark